# Launch an Android Wear app with a “Start …” voice command

Tags: wear-os

I try to launch my wear app by Start voice command. I followed the documentation 
[Adding Voice Capabilities](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/voice.html#AppProvided). But when I try to launch the app by saying (OK Google) "Start my app" I receive  the Google Now web search results back for the topics related to  the "Start my app" instead of  launching the app itself.

```
<activity
        android:label="my app"
        android:name=".MainActivityWear"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity
```

My feeling is that the documentation is outdated and the Start command used to be in older versions of Android wear.
(My version is 1.3.0 with OS 5.1.1.)
I think so, because in my version of the wear to activate the Speak Now card I have to say "OK Google" or swipe the screen from left. The Settings/Launcher with the app list is 2 pages left from the Speak Now card, rather than at the bottom of the card as mentioned in this documentation:
[Wearable Applications Launch](http://android-wear-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/wearable.html).
Especially the part saying the following  looks unfamiliar to my watch behaviour:

> To manually launch the app, touch the watch face and scroll to the last action, which is “Start...”. Then select your app from the list of installed apps, in this case First_Wearable.

Is anyone able to launch apps in watch by START voice command?
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The "Adding Voice Capabilities" in official documentation is accurate and up to date; I just tried "Start ***" for two different apps, one pre-installed and one development app (Jumping Jack sample) and both worked just fine (you can use launch instead of start as well). The second documentation you reference is not official and that seems to be outdated.

Comment: Can you please tell which version of OS and Wear in your watch you have and what make of watch? I really cannot do neither Start or Launch. Both commands give me Google search results instead. I tried also the Jumping Jack sample you mentioned.

Comment: What language is your phone set to? Many voice actions are language specific.

Comment: I am having the same problem: "Start X" or "Launch X" for other apps on the watch works, but not for mine. Language is English, watch is G Watch, Build number M1D63H.

Comment: (Clarification: Android Wear version 1.5.0.3058194, OS version 6.0.1, Play Services version 9.4.52 (534-127739847)

Comment: Dis you try another name for your app? May be, "my app" is somehow reserved.

Comment: Maybe it's split. Does "Start my" work to start your app, out of curiosity? And does "Start someOtherApp" work (for the built-in ones, f.ex.)?

Comment: How about "open" and "launch" instead of start, as described in http://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-launch-apps-on-android-wear/?

Comment: I've tried "Start" and "Launch," haven't tried "Open" yet. Note that "start" and "launch" both work for other apps on this watch.

I've also tried a couple of app names (App's actual name is "Butler," which I don't think is reserved? And I get search results for "Butler," so it's keying in to the words correctly; it just thinks I want to search, not launch an app).

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a custom activity command. See [the docs](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/voice.html)

```
<application>
  <activity 
      android:name="StartRunActivity" 
      android:label="my app">
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
  </activity>
</application>
```

Instead, you used:

```
<activity
    android:label="my app"
    android:name=".MainActivityWear"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

You used ".MainActivityWear" ->  instead of: "StartRunActivity"

That may be a keyword, I'm not sure, or maybe the dot in the name is causing the problem.

Also, try it without the theme.

And do you have everything under the  tag?